# Router reuse strategy unables access to query params

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have implemented custom router reuse strategy. To my surprise every time I enable the custom router reuse strategy, `queryParams` in `navbar` component (defined below) become undefined. If I disable custom reuse strategy, `navbar` component can get access to queryParams.

**< UPDATE >**

I've created a toy example project showing the problem and tried to upload it to plnkr, but unfortunately I don't know how to tell it to run the code live. The uploaded code is from src folder:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ub7Pns8EOAYn2pfXtEsY?p=preview

If you manage to run it, then just open up developer tools and see console.logs. project and data query params set in `navbar` are NaN in the case of custom reuse strategy, but are set accordingly if reuse strategy is disabled.

**< / UPDATE >**

This is the code:

```
   import { ActivatedRoute, Routes, RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

    queryParams(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        let path = route.root.firstChild.url.map((x) => {
            return x.path;
        }).reduce((x, y) => {
            return x + "/" + y;
        });
        return path + "/" + this.getProject(route) + "&" + this.getdata(route);
    }
    getProject(snap: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        if (snap.queryParams.project) {
            return "project=" + snap.queryParams.project;
        }
        return "";
    }
    getdata(snap: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        if (snap.queryParams.data) {
            return "data=" + snap.queryParams.data;
        }
        return "";
    }
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log("should detach: ",this.queryParams(route).includes("project") && this.queryParams(route).includes("data"));

        return this.queryParams(route).includes("project") && this.queryParams(route).includes("data"); 
    }
    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)] = handle;
    }
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log("future: ",future, "this.queryParams(future) ",this.queryParams(future));

        return !!this.handlers[this.queryParams(future)];
    }
    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        console.error("!!this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)] ", !!this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)],"this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)] ",this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)]);
        if (!!this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)]) {
            return this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)];
        }
        return null
    }
    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!this.handlers[this.queryParams(route)];
    }
}
```

Idea is to reuse snapshots if urls contain `project` and `data` query string parameter.

In app.component.html I have:

```
<app-navbar>
</app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`navbar.ts` has the following code:

```
//ngOnInit
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.projectNumber = parseInt(params.has("project") ? params.get("project") : undefined);
      this.dataNumber = parseInt(params.has("data") ? params.get("data") : undefined);
      console.log("this.projectNumber in projects; " + this.projectNumber);
   });
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are query params undefined in the case of custom reuse strategy?

Moreover,  components that are used 'inside' the `router-outlet` can access queryParams as usual.